# C++, struct init multiple instances

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct init by:

```
nodeBuf = new Node[num](); //num is some number of different instances of this struct
```

I understand that this creates num instances of my struct. But I'm not sure how to access each instance.

I tried nodeBuf[num], does not work

Comment: You ought to tell us how you typed the variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `num > 0` only `nodeBuf[0]` until `nodeBuf[num -1]` are valid. If `num == 0` then accessing the elements by the index operator is not allwed (= UB).

Sample:

```
struct Node
{
  std::string name;
};

void f()
{
  int num = 4;
  Node* nodeBuf = new Node[num];
  nodeBuf[1].name = "Test";
  delete[] nodeBuf;
}
```

Comment: ah I see, any reason why nodeBuf[1].name works buy nodeBuf[1]->name doesnt?

Comment: nodeBuf is of type `Node*`, but since `E1[E2]` is `*((E1)+(E2))` (note the dereference) then nodeBuf[1] is of type `Node` and the arrow operator can't be used since it's `pointer to member`.